# Sending different datatype data in single CAN message in STM32

Tags: floating-point, boolean, stm32, bytebuffer, can-bus

While working with the CAN on STM32L4, I am trying to send three different data types of data i.e. float, bool and float value. As in one message 8 byte can be sent, all three data I am sending in single message.

my data looks like

```
float tf;
uint16_t sl;
bool status_tf;
bool status_sl;
```

It would be great if I can get some direction, How I can combine all three data type in single CAN message?

Until now, I have tried with `sprintf()` with print format specifier. and storing combined result in `char TxData[8];` But Not getting any fruitful result.

To send the data, standard `HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage()` used.

```
HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox);
```

Comment: `scanf`? How did you use it? Normally, such a text processing function isn't used/needed in CAN Bus. Please provide a code snippet about it, so we can understand your use case and suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Sorry in hurry, I did written 'scanf' instead of 'sprintf()' I packed my data like below. char TxData[8] = {0}; sprintf(TxData, 8, "%f%d%d%d", tf, sl, status_tf,status_sl ); HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox);

Comment: This method was not good method so i wanted to change to standard packing method. Thanks to @chux I could pack all data in one CAN_message.   Now  I have used; uint8_t TxData[8]={0}; memcpy();   for 'float' and 'uint16_t' and for boolean I have toggled bit using  "bytes ^=  0b00000001 << 1 (for sl_status) ",  "bytes ^=  0b00000001 << 2 (for tf_status) " and  memcpy(&TxData[7], &bytes, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can combine all three data type in single CAN message?

At first blush, one might consider a `struct` to hold all the data and then send that.

```
// First idea, but is it too big?
typedef struct {
  float tf;
  uint16_t sl;
  bool status_tf;
  bool status_sl;
} my_data;
```

The size of `my_data` may be more than 8 bytes due to padding and `bool` may be more than 1 byte.

Consider using `memcpy()` to cope with alignment issues.  A good compiler will emit efferent code for such small copies.  I'd assign the `bool` to `charTxData[6]` (& 7) to cope with a wide `bool`.  Only the value of 0 or 1 will assign.

```
unsigned char TxData[8];

memcpy(&charTxData[0], &tf, 4);
memcpy(&charTxData[4], &sl, 2);
charTxData[6] = status_tf;
charTxData[7] = status_sl;

HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox);
```

To recover the data, reverse the copying.

---

Pedantic code would also check sizes:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof tf == 4, "Unusual tf size");
_Static_assert(sizeof sl == 2, "Unusual sl size");
```

If endian-ness of `uint16_t` and/or `float` or `float` encoding may differ, additional code is warranted.

Comment: The bools will likely need a more careful conversion. There will be a protocol specifying exactly which bits they correspond to and that doesn't necessarily correspond to the internal respresentation of  a bool in the C program. Similarly, care must be taken to adjust the larger data types to network endianess - you might not be able to use memcpy.

Comment: @Lundin In standard C `bool` used, which bits uses does not make a difference with `charTxData[6] = status_tf;` or the reverse `status_tf = charTxData[6];`.   `charTxData[6]` will receive the value of 0 or 1.  The `bool` is not copied via `mempy()` here.

Comment: @Lundin True about endianness concerns for `float, uint16_t`.  Also `float`, even if same endianness and size, might use different encoding.

Comment: Ah yeah that's true. But it seems like a waste to use 2 bytes to store 2 bits though. CAN bandwidth is always tight. Regarding endianess, there's all manner of strange flavours out there. For example industry standard CANopen uses Big Endian identifiers (as required by the CAN standard) but Little Endian payload.

Comment: @Lundin Of course cracking the egg on the little end is the [correct choice](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Spring_2003/ling538/Lecnotes/ADfn1.htm).

Comment: No, obviously it should be cracked at the big end! :) Related, I wrote a little self-answered Q&A about it here: [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640) There's a link to the original Cohen article there too, in case anyone is interested in reading it.

Comment: @Lundin (nice Q/A).  Note: Rule exception to "Motorola one stores data in the order numbers are read in English" as English has its inconsistencies/_richness_ --> [13 or thirteen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thirteen#Etymology) , a little endian "three” + “teen”.

Comment: What I meant with that is 0x1234 is read left-to-right as in English: one two three four. And stored as 0x1234 in big endian.